# make a dropdown from string type in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

model code....

```
    public class ConfigureModel
    {
        public bool Responsive { get; set; }

        public string Theams { get; set; }

    }
```

---

controller

```
        ConfigureModel model = new ConfigureModel();

        model.Responsive = bootStrapCoreSettings.Responsive ;

        //model.Theams = bootStrapCoreSettings.Theams;

        var theams = "lsdjfldsk;lkdfjlsd;jldskfj;dlksfj;";

        model.Theams = them.Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

---

how to put theams values in to dropdown...

need a guideline or code

Comment: model.Theams = them.Split(new char[] { ';' }); // is really compiled??

Answer (score 2):

For using the Html.Dropdownlist in your view you need to have a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList` in your model. So your model will change like this:

```
public class ConfigureModel
{
    public bool Responsive { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> TheamsList { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller will have :

```
    var theams = "lsdjfldsk;lkdfjlsd;jldskfj;dlksfj;";
    List<string> myList = theams.TrimEnd(';').Split(';').ToList();
    model.TheamsList = myList;
```

After you have filled your model, code in the Razor view will be like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Theams", Model.TheamsList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Model Code

```
public class ConfigureModel
{
    public bool Responsive { get; set; }

    public SelectList TheamsList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTheam { get; set; }
}
```

Action Code

```
ConfigureModel model = new ConfigureModel();
var theams = "lsdjfldsk;lkdfjlsd;jldskfj;dlksfj;";

// If you don't want a blank value for the bit after the last ';'
theams = theams.TrimEnd(';');

var theamsSplit = theams.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToDictionary(s => s, s => s);
model.TheamsList = new SelectList(theams, "Key", "Value");
```

View Code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTheam, Model.TheamsList)
```

Tangent: Did you mean Themes instead of Theams?

Comment: Missed the MVC 4 in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not even compile:

```
// You try to assign an array to a string
model.Theams = them.Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

Try changing the configure model class to:

```
public class ConfigureModel
{
    public bool Responsive { get; set; }

    public List<string> Theams { get; set; }

}
```

and your calling code to something like (sample to demonstrate not best practice);

```
var theams = "lsdjfldsk;lkdfjlsd;jldskfj;dlksfj;";
theams.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToList().ForEach(theam => {
    model.Theams.Add(theam);
});
```

Then you have a filled model. Use this in your razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Theams, new SelectList(Model.Theams))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

model.Theams should be of array type.

after converting it to List or array just pass it to `@HTML.EditorFor(model=> Theams)`
it will be dropdown.